# simple question about if statement in c sharp

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to do a simple task. I'm trying to make an if statement for my program where if the user enters a number less than 100, it multiplies by .1 and shows the answer in a message box. But everytime I run the program the message box gives me back 0 for an answer rather than 6.5 for 65 for example. I am probably just missing something easy in my code here, please take a look.

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private double discountAmt;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DiscountCalculation(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double Price = 0;
        double.Parse(PriceBox.Text);

        if (Price < 100)
        {

         discountAmt = (Price * .1);

            MessageBox.Show(" The discount is " + discountAmt.ToString());
        }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to assign the parsed value, e.g. `double Price = double.Parse(PriceBox.Text);`

Comment: Thanks for your help that fixed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
double.Parse(PriceBox.Text);
```

It parses the textbox, but doesn't do anything with the result. You want this:

```
double Price = double.Parse(PriceBox.Text);
```

Even better is to use `double.TryParse()`, and also when working with money use the `decimal` type rather than `double`.

```
private void DiscountCalculation(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal Price = 0.0m;
    if (decimal.TryParse(PriceBox.Text, out Price) && Price < 100)
    {
        discountAmt = (Price * .1);
        MessageBox.Show($"The discount is {discountAmt}");
    }
}
```